# Как можно сделать переход на новую строку?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я пробовал использовать \n и console.writeline() , но не помогало
сам код:

```
    private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool elogin;
        bool epass;

        string login = "ivan";
        string password = "12345";
        if (enter_login.Text == "ivan")
            nickname = "Ivan";
        else nickname = " ";
        if (enter_login.Text == login)
            elogin = true;
        else
            elogin = false;
        if (enter_password.Text == password)
            epass = true;
        else
            epass = false;
        if (elogin == true && epass == true)
            panel1.Visible = false;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Неверный логин или пароль");
        list_chat.Text += nickname; 
    }

    private void enter_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = " ";
        message = enter_chat.Text;
        chat_window.Text += "[" + nickname + "]: " + message.ToString() + "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если контрол `chat_window` вообще разрешает многострочный текст, то для переноса строки пользуйтесь универсальным свойством [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx).

Также не советую пользоваться в вашем случае конкатенацией строк. Дело в том, что строки неизменяемые, поэтому вы каждый раз будете создавать новые и новые экземпляры строк, что увеличит потребление памяти. Лучше пользоваться методом [`AppendText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx).